# Python :Wave.readframe to numpy areay for fft

Tags: python, numpy, audio, fft, wave

Ist there a way to convert the Data from wave.readframe(chunk) to a numpy Array for fft?

( reading from wav File to numpy Array is not an Option because i read the wav File from a pipe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`wavio` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wavio) that I wrote includes the function `_wav2array(nchannels, sampwidth, data)` that does what you want.  (You can also [find it on github](https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/wavio).)

To use it, you need:

- the number of audio channels as returned by the [`getnchannels()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html#wave.Wave_read.getnchannels),
- the sample width as returned by the [`getsampwidth()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html#wave.Wave_read.getsampwidth),
- and the data returned by the [`readframes(n)` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html#wave.Wave_read.readframes).

Then you can write

```
array = _wav2array(nchannels, sampwidth, data)
```

Comment: works for me i think thanks :) but i have trouble using my fft results for stuff like beatdetection , any hints what to use , i get a large array form this : `code` array = wavio._wav2array(1, 2,data)
   fft=abs(np.fft.rfft(array)) `code` should i average over the lower part for getting the amplitude of the low freqs ?

Comment: Your question has two parts: (1) how to convert the data returned by `readframes(n)` into a numpy array, and  (2) how to use the FFT to analyze your data.  My answer here is for the first part.  The second part deserves its own question, either here on stackoverflow or over at [dsp.stackexchange.com](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

You have to compute the fft on several samples (256 for example), thus you need to read several frames at the same time.

Something like this should work:

```
import wave, struct
from numpy.fft import rfft

nb_samples = 256
sampwidth = waveFile.getsampwidth()
datatypes = (None, "%iB", "%ih", None) 
datatype = fmts[sampwidth]

waveData = waveFile.readframes(nb_samples)
frame = struct.unpack(datatype % nb_frames, waveData)
fft = abs(rfft(frame))**2
```

Comment: i get this  error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./wav.py", line 55, in <module>
    frame = struct.unpack("%dh" % nb_samples, waveData)
struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 512

Comment: @spam junk. This depend of your data type. I updated the answer to read a mono wav file with different format (8 and 16 bit). If your file is stereo, you have to use also the number of channel to read the data.